# How do i get data from the gcm?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

Can someone show me the hierarchy that stands behind the process when I'm getting a new data from the GCM? The process that happened only in the client. Example: First the data is getting to the displayMessage function in CommonUtilities class. Seconds the data is transmitted to the onMessage function in GCMIntentService class, and so on.

Thanks!

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

        // Showing received message
        lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the process with registering the device and getting the `registrationId` is passes as it should be, getting the data in your `onMessage()` should be something similar to this :

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

            Log.d(TAG, "MESSAGE RECEIVED : "+intent.getExtras().toString());
            String action  = intent.getStringExtra("action");
            int extra = 0;
            try {
                    extra = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("action_id"));
            } catch (Exception e){
                    /* ignore */
            }
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), message, action, extra);
    }
```

Of course this is in my app, the keys which you will use to get the right data depends on what kind of data is sending your server to the client device. And after receiving this portion of data you can do whatever you like with it, maybe create a notification and alert the user about the message.

**Edit :**

If you want to show some kind of message in your activity using `BroadcastReceiver` you can do something like this : In your `onMessage` after receiving the message send `broadcastIntent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent("messageReceived");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and add

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(messageReceived);
```

to your activity and register your broadcast receiver like :

```
 registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

and handler the message in your receiver like this :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("messageReceived")) {
         // Do your stuff here.
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank for you answer! Should I just ignore from all the things that happen that aren't in the MainActivity? I'm talking only about the process of getting message. The intent that mentioned here is getting his extras from the server? not from onMessage function?

Comment: To get message from GCM you have to create a Service which extends `GCMBaseIntentService` and Override the functions. After registering the device you will receive the messages using that service and depending on that you can show whatever you want, you won't receive the messages in your activity. Correct me if I understand you wrong.

Comment: I'm talking only on the client and ignoring what happen in the server. My question is if I get the data only through the onReceive function, or the data is going first through another function that I need to consider? I hope I explain my self well.

Comment: You are receiving the data in `onMessage` and that's the only function you need to take care of.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking so much, but I have one more question please. What is the purpose of the onReceive function?  Thank you a lot!

Comment: What onReceive function are you talking about?

Comment: I have onReceive function in my MainActivity, I will edit my question.

Comment: that onReceive is not connected with GCM, but you can make it if you need to display a certain message in your activity after receiving message from GCM. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! When I will have enough reputation I will vote you answer :)

Comment: Are data always passed as Strings in the intent extra? For example, you do `Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("action_id"))`. Is there no way to `getIntExtra("action_id")` directly?

Comment: How do you get the action_id? don't know how to get it?